# Чтение данных из базы Oracle

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Нужно считать данные из таблицы базы Oracle. Делается это в консольном приложении. Вот мой код:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=XE;User ID=Mydb;Password=111292;Unicode=True");
con.Open();
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter("select name from test2", con);
Console.WriteLine(da);
con.Close();
Console.ReadKey();
```

Но таким вот способом я вывожу не мой селект а просто тип данных OracleClient. Как можно вывести именно то что я написал в запросе и желательно считать это в стринг. В дальнейшем мне нужно распарсить данные по полям. Но это уже потом сейчас не могу понять как вообще их считать. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: @Mike если можете помогите пожалуйста с вопросом.

Comment: Попробуйте `OracleCommand`

Comment: @0xdb а можно поконкретней? Можете вариант привести.

Comment: Вам уже предложили один ответ.

Comment: @0xdb он не совсем подошёл. Я уже попробовал.

Comment: Не перживайте, сейчас накидают ещё ответов. Здесь шарпистов чуть меньше, чем звёзд на небе.

Comment: @0xdb хорошо, подожду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Извлечение данных с помощью DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/haa3afyz.aspx)

Пример с `Oracle`:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select id from test", connection))
    {
        using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                long id = reader.GetInt64(0);
                Console.WriteLine(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Чтобы извлекать поля типа `XmlType` используйте метод [`reader.GetOracleXmlType();`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1021203), либо преобразовывайте его в строку на стороне СУБД как показано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35039900/6766879

Comment: попробовал ваш вариант. Только чуть чуть изменил под свои поля само собой. На строчке `OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()` вылетела ошибка вот с таким вот текстом: `Additional information: Обнаружен неподдерживаемый тип данных Oracle USERDEFINED.` Не могу понять в чём проблема. Может быть вы подскажите?

Comment: вот мой код: `con.Open();
                using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(str, con))
                {
                    using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            String name = reader.GetString(0);
                            Console.WriteLine(name);
                        }
                    }
                }` тут всё кроме строки подключения. Просто не умещается в комментарий)

Comment: @Андрей, сам текст запроса покажите

Comment: `String str = "select name from test2";` тип поля name XMLType. Туда из приложения ASP.NET записывается содержимое xml файла. Надеюсь это поможет.

Comment: Он же даже в самом вопросе есть если что.

Comment: И кстати почему то когда я пишу @Андрей. Ваш ник почему то просто пропадает. Почему так? потому что у меня такой же ник? Но вы как то ставите мой ник. Как это сделать. Но это уже не принципиально)

Comment: @Андрей, проблема в несовместимости типов, для чтения полей типа `XmlType` нужен и метод соответствующий. Добавил в ответ.

Comment: если вы говорите про строчку `String name = reader.GetString(0);` то у меня нет такого типа почему то. Есть другие оракловские но XMLType почему то нет. Может нужна дополнительно какая то библиотека?

Comment: @Андрей, я использую Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

Comment: Либо, как вариант, вам нужно в самом sql запросе кастовать XMLType в строку, как показано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35039900/6766879

Comment: Вроде разобрался, спасибо. У меня конечно работает но для уверенности спрошу, вот так должен выглядеть запрос. `String str = "select T.name.getClobVal() as name from test2 T";` ?

Comment: Да я сейчас поставлю спасибо большое. Только вопрос ещё есть. `GetString(0)` это я так понял читается по символьно. И 2 строчки у меня читало примерно секунд 15. А это как то можно ускорить считав сразу всё или это единственный вариант?

Comment: А всё. Похоже просто программа зависла. В отладке увидел что всё читается сразу. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Андрей, чтение происходит построчно. При вызове метода `reader.Read()` курсор перемещается к следующей строчке. Когда разберетесь с командами, рекомендую посмотреть библиотеку `Dapper` - с ней вам не придется построчно читать из ридера, а можно получить готовую типизированную коллекцию объектов